# PayPal IPN returning full php ascii code instead of just a numeric value

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

So I'm passing a custom value to PayPal:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

However when it's returning the custom variable back it sometimes returns it as:

EITHER THIS: custom=%3C%3Fphp+echo+9445%3B+%3F%3E

OR THIS: 2. custom=9445

It's random. Sometimes it returns it properly (custom=9445) and other times it returns it as %3C%3Fphp+echo+9445%3B+%3F%3E. Which messes up the other functions while storing into the database and correlating it to a certain user. Am I missing something? Did I do something wrong?

Full form code:

```
 <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
   <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
   <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXXXXXXXX">
   <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
   <input type="image" src="http://www.XXXXXX.com/XXX/XXXX/XXXXXX.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
   <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
 </form>
```

Comment: post the full form code

Comment: I think thats also inside the php tag

Comment: posted full form code!